# Android: set TextView width dynamically in relation to other view elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I got this `TextView` `basket_item_list_options`. The text of this `TextView` is set dynamically and can be very long.

**The problem is**, that if it is long the three `Button` on the right side of this `TextView` are pushed out of view. I would like to set the width of this `TextView` that the `Button` are still in view and it just uses more lines (using more height) for itself.

Does anyone know what I need to change to do that? Or do I need to do this programmatically?

This is how it looks, when the TextView content is not too much:

[image]

The String "Nichts: Stuff;" is the content of the `TextView`. If this content is too much, the three `buttons` on the right are pushed out of view.

**Here is code of Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_itemname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
            android:text="ItemName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Options" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="-" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
        android:text="-"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_garbage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shop_sample" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="1€"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="nx"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your output too.

Comment: could you add your screensort image

Comment: place a TextView and buttons inside a RelativeLayout, and make textview to align to the right side of the buttons. This way buttons will take as much space as they need, adn TextView will take all the rest space

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Please see my edit.

Comment: @progNewbie do you want plus ,minus and delete image on right side ?

Comment: Can you add what exactly you want , post your image.@progNewbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code , here i'm talking `LinearLayout` as parent and inside it all layouts are `LinearLayout`.You can change your `weight` according to your need.

[image]

**Structure :**

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout> //weight 
          <ImageView>
          <TextView>
    </LinearLayout> 

   <LinearLayout>//weight 
          //all Buttons
   </LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the Full Code :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_list_item"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />



        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_itemname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
                android:text="Item"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Options" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:minWidth="1dp"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="-" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="-"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="1€"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="nx"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weightSum` attribute of `LinearLayout` to equally distribute available space between views. please refer to example code below, ragards.

I have put weightSum=10 which variable, you can put as per your requirement and distribute than sum to child views which will occupy space wrt to weightSum percentage

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10"
android:padding="5dp">
   <TextView 
     android:layout_weight="7"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:text="some text"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <Button
     android:text="btn1"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <Button
     android:text="btn2"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <Button
     android:text="btn3"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do this it will help you definately :-**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_itemname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_image"
            android:text="ItemName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Options"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this solution?

Comment: you have used wrapContent in linearLayout it means it can adjust by length of textview so I gave fix width in linearlayout, textview will adjust according to linearlayout width.

Comment: The problem with fixed width is, that it is not responsive.

Comment: what do you exactly need?

Answer (score 0):

Use weightSum concept for better results. First make it as two separate layouts, one is for description & another is for three buttons. Now take one parent layout with these two layouts as child with some respective layout weights. Parent layout should be sum of the two child individual weights.

For ref:  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-layout-weight-weightsum-ramasamy-kasiviswanathan/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `weight` parameter on your `Views`. Then your row elements will be fixed size than you should use horizontal scroll on the `TextView`.
Example of using `weight`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You should insert another `LinearLayout` in the line where should be some objects (*f.e. buttons, images...*). `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` and `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` `TextView` parameters says that text will be displayed only in fixed size `TextView` and it will not cover other views if it will have very long text.
**Notice that parent layout width could not be `wrap_content`.**